# Merging multiple files with two common columns, and replace the blank to 0

Tags: bash, awk, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format, bed

I extremely appreciate if anyone could me help to merge multiple files (up to 8) with two common columns ($1$2). I want to get all values of $3 and replace the blank with 0. Here are the samples from 4 files

File1:

```
chr1 111001 234
chr2 22099  108
```

File2:

```
chr1 111001 42
chr1 430229 267
```

File3:

```
chr1 111001 92
chr5 663800 311
```

File4:

```
chr1 111001 129
chr2 22099  442
```

Desired output

```
chr1 111001 234 42 92 129
chr1 430229  0  267 0  0
chr2 22099  108 0  0  442
chr5 663800  0  0 311  0
```

I tried

```
awk '{ a[$1 OFS $2 FS] = a[$1 OFS $2 FS] ( a[$1 OFS $2 FS] == "" ? "" : OFS) $3 }END{ for (i in a){print i,"0",a[i]} }' OFS="\t"  file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt | sort -k1
```

output

```
chr1    111001  0   234 42  92  129
chr1    430229  0   267
chr2    22099   0   108 442
chr5    663800  0   311
```

Thank very much in advance

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, as its highly recommended on SO.

Comment: It's too bad `join` only works with 2 files at a time.

Comment: Can `chr1 111001` appear more than once in same file?

Comment: No, just once each file @anubhava

Comment: @Shawn, this code can merge multiple files 
`awk '{ a[$1 OFS $2 FS] = a[$1 OFS $2 FS] ( a[$1 OFS $2 FS] == "" ? "" : OFS) $3 }END{ for (i in a){print i,a[i]} }'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more variant, could you please try following, written and teste with shown samples.

```
awk '
{
  if(!a[FILENAME]++){
     file[++count]=FILENAME
  }
  b[$1 OFS $2 OFS FILENAME]=$NF
  c[$1 OFS $2]++
  if(!d[$1 OFS $2]++){
    e[++count1]=$1 OFS $2
  }
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=length(c);i++){
    printf("%s ",e[i])
    for(j=1;j<=count;j++){
      printf("%s %s",(b[e[i] OFS file[j]]!=""?b[e[i] OFS file[j]]:0),j==count?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
}
' file{1..4} | sort -k1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
chr1 111001 234  42  92  129
chr1 430229 0  267  0  0
chr2 22099 108  0  0  442
chr5 663800 0  0  311  0
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  if(!a[FILENAME]++){                        ##Checking condition if FILENAME is present in a then do following.
     file[++count]=FILENAME                  ##Creating file with index of count and value is current file name.
  }
  b[$1 OFS $2 OFS FILENAME]=$NF              ##Creating array b with index of 1st 2nd and filename and which has value as last field.
  c[$1 OFS $2]++                             ##Creating array c with index of 1st and 2nd field and keep increasing its value with 1.
  if(!d[$1 OFS $2]++){                       ##Checking condition if 1st and 2nd field are NOT present in d then do following.
    e[++count1]=$1 OFS $2                    ##Creating e with index of count1 with increasing value of 1 and which has first and second fields here.
  }
}
END{                                         ##Starting END block of this awk program from here.
  for(i=1;i<=length(c);i++){                 ##Starting for loop which runs from i=1 to till length of c here.
    printf("%s ",e[i])                       ##Printing value of array e with index i here.
    for(j=1;j<=count;j++){                   ##Starting for loop till value of count here.
      printf("%s %s",(b[e[i] OFS file[j]]!=""?b[e[i] OFS file[j]]:0),j==count?ORS:OFS)   ##Printing value of b with index of e[i] OFS file[j] if it present then print else print 0, print new line if j==count or print space.
    }
  }
}
' file{1..4} | sort -k1                      ##Mentioning Input_files 1 to 4 here and sorting output with 1st field here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per GREAT regex GURU @anubhava sir's comments adding solution with `ARGC` and `ARGV` with GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  b[$1 OFS $2 OFS FILENAME]=$NF
  c[$1 OFS $2]++
  if(!d[$1 OFS $2]++){
    e[++count1]=$1 OFS $2
  }
}
END{
  count=(ARGC-1)
  for(i=1;i<=length(c);i++){
    printf("%s ",e[i])
    for(j=1;j<=(ARGC-1);j++){
      printf("%s %s",(b[e[i] OFS ARGV[j]]!=""?b[e[i] OFS ARGV[j]]:0),j==count?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
}
' file{1..4} | sort -k1
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `gnu-awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   for (k=1; k<ARGC; ++k)
      s = s " " 0
}
{
   key=$1 OFS $2
   if (!(key in map))
      map[key] = s
   map[key] = gensub("^( ([0-9]+ ){" ARGIND-1 "})[0-9]+", "\\1" $3, "1", map[key])
}
END {
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
   for (k in map)
      print k map[k]
}' file{1..4} | column -t
```

```
chr1  111001  234  42   92   129
chr1  430229  0    267  0    0
chr2  22099   108  0    0    442
chr5  663800  0    0    311  0
```

**Explanation:**

- We are building a string with all zeroes, one for each file in arguments
- Using `gensub` we build a regex using `ARGIND` (current argument index)
- This regex replaces `0` in current `ARGIND`th position with `$3`
- `END` block just prints out associative array content stored in `map`
- `column -t` is used for tabular display of data

---

Here is an equivalent command to make it work in POSIX `awk` (non-gnu):

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   for (k=1; k<ARGC; ++k)
      s = s " " 0
}
FNR == 1 {
   ++argind
}
{
   key=$1 OFS $2
   if (!(key in map))
      map[key] = s
   split(map[key], a)
   a[argind] = $3
   v = ""
   for (k=1; k<ARGC; ++k)
      v = v " " a[k]
   map[key]=v
}
END {
   for (k in map)
      print k map[k]
}' file{1..4}
```

Comment: I really appreciate it
It works perfectly, I am not really familiar with ARGIND argument though, and it is a good start for me to work on that

Comment: Not knowing something is an opportunity to learn something new, isn't it? btw `ARGIND` is just a variable in 2nd POSIX code there we could use ``var` instead of `ARGIND` as well.

Comment: Or in gawk simpler `gensub(" [0-9]+"," "$3,ARGIND,map[key])` -- and personally I would skip the `if` and do `map[key] = gensub(... key in map? map[key]: s)`

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085, excellent suggestion to optimize it further.

Answer (score 2):

These files look like they are derived from bed of vcf files. If so, do not reinvent the wheel. Use any of specialized bioinformatics tools to manipulate these files. For example: [`bedtools`](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/overview.html),
[`bcftools`](http://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html),
[`Picard MergeVcfs`](https://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/command-line-overview.html#MergeVcfs), etc

Find more by searching for `merge bed files` or `merge vcf files`. Most of these bioinformatics tools/packages can be installed using `conda` from `bioconda` channel.

After the bed/vcf files are merged/joined/intersected/etc, use common *NIX utilities and scripting languages to extract and manipulate the files when they are **not** in any of the common bioinformatics formats.

Comment: I really appreciate you suggestion. But, I really need this kind of script because I have other files cannot be process with `bedtools` as well