# How to merge multiple files with two common columns, and name the added col as file name?

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, bed

I'm trying to merge multiple `.bed` files by identifying the first two columns `chr` and `start` following this,

[Merging multiple files with two common columns, and replace the blank to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64085218/merging-multiple-files-with-two-common-columns-and-replace-the-blank-to-0)

However, I'm wondering how to make the file name a newly added column name.

```
$cat combineFWPS_02.sh

    BEGIN {
       for (k=1; k<ARGC; ++k)
          s = s " " 0
    }
    FNR == 1 {
       ++ARGIND
    }
    {
       key=$1 OFS $2
       if (!(key in map))
          map[key] = s
       split(map[key], a)
       a[ARGIND] = $3
       v = ""
       for (k=1; k<ARGC; ++k)
          v = v " " a[k]
       map[key]=v
    }
    END {
       for (k in map)
          print k map[k]
    }

$cat comRwps_02.sh

awkCOM="~/scripts/combineFWPS_02.sh"
## Run the jobs
time awk -f $awkCOM *.xyz.bed | sort -k1 >  13jLiC.xyz.txt
```

The input files look like this:

```
FF85561.xyz.bed:

chr1 111001 234
chr2 22099  108
chr5 463100 219

FF85574.xyz.bed:

chr1 111001 42
chr1 430229 267
chr5 663800 319

FF85631.xyz.bed:

chr1 111001 92
chr3 22099  144
chr5 663800 311

FF85717.xyz.bed:

chr1 111001 129
chr1 157901 79
chr2 22099  442
```

The expected output file would be

```
$head 13jLiC.xyz.txt

chr    start    FF85561    FF85574    FF85631    FF85717
chr1   111001    234         42          92         129
chr1   157901      0          0           0          79
chr1   430229      0        267           0           0
chr2    22099    108          0           0         442
chr3    22099      0          0         144           0
chr5   463100    219          0           0           0
chr5   663800      0        319         311           0
```

Comment: Naming a `awk` program file `something.sh` is a bit strange.

Comment: You might want to name the variable `argind` instead of `ARGIND` so that if it's ever run on a system that happens to have GNU awk it doesn't break (or need to be changed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
    vals[++numRows,++numCols] = "chr"
    vals[numRows,++numCols] = "start"
}
FNR == 1 {
    val = FILENAME
    sub(/\..*/,"",val)
    vals[1,++numCols] = val
}
{
    key = $1 FS $2
    if ( !(key in key2rowNr) ) {
        key2rowNr[key] = ++numRows
        vals[numRows,1] = $1
        vals[numRows,2] = $2
    }
    rowNr = key2rowNr[key]
    vals[rowNr,numCols] = $3
}
END {
    for ( rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++ ) {
        for ( colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++ ) {
            val = ( (rowNr,colNr) in vals ? vals[rowNr,colNr] : 0 )
            row = ( colNr>1 ? row OFS : "" ) val
        }
        print row
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk *.bed
chr     start   FF85561 FF85574 FF85631 FF85717
chr1    111001  234     42      92      129
chr2    22099   108     0       0       442
chr5    463100  219     0       0       0
chr1    430229  0       267     0       0
chr5    663800  0       319     311     0
chr3    22099   0       0       144     0
chr1    157901  0       0       0       79
```

and if you want the rows sorted then you can apply a [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Decorate-sort-undecorate_idiom) approach:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk *.bed | awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>1), $0}' | sort -k1,1n -k2,2 -k3,3n | cut -f2-
chr     start   FF85561 FF85574 FF85631 FF85717
chr1    111001  234     42      92      129
chr1    157901  0       0       0       79
chr1    430229  0       267     0       0
chr2    22099   108     0       0       442
chr3    22099   0       0       144     0
chr5    463100  219     0       0       0
chr5    663800  0       319     311     0
```

If the `chr<number>` string can ever have more than 1 digit at the end and you want those sorted both alphabetically and numerically (e.g. so `chr2` comes before `chr10`) then you'd have to change the DSU part to something like:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk *.bed | awk -v OFS='\t' '{c=$1; sub(/[[:alpha:]]+/,"&" OFS,c); print (NR>1), c, $0}' | sort -k1,1n -k2,2 -k3,3 -k5,5n | cut -f4-
chr     start   FF85561 FF85574 FF85631 FF85717
chr1    111001  234     42      92      129
chr1    157901  0       0       0       79
chr1    430229  0       267     0       0
chr2    22099   108     0       0       442
chr3    22099   0       0       144     0
chr5    463100  219     0       0       0
chr5    663800  0       319     311     0
```

Answer (score 5):

In GNU `awk`, with your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` solution.

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
FNR==1{
  split(FILENAME,fileName,".")
  files[++count]=fileName[1]
}
{
  baseArr[$1 OFS $2]
  arr1[$1 OFS $2]=(arr1[$1 OFS $2]?arr1[$1 OFS $2] OFS:"") $3
  keyPresense[$1 OFS $2 OFS fileName[1]]=$3
}
END{
  printf("%s ","chr start")
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    printf("%s%s",files[i],i==count?ORS:OFS)
  }
  for(j in baseArr){
    for(k=1;k<=count;k++){
      if(j OFS files[k] in keyPresense){
         foundCount++
      }
    val=(val?val OFS:"") (j OFS files[k] in keyPresense? OFS keyPresense[j OFS files[k]]:"0")
    }
    print j,foundCount==length(files)?arr1[j]:val
    val=foundCount=""
  }
}
' *.bed | column -t | sort -sk1
```

Answer (score 3):

Either add at the beginning of the END block

```
    t="chr start"; for(k=1;k<ARGC;++k) t=t OFS ARGV[k]; gsub(/.xyz.bed/,"",t); print t
    # can use " " instead of OFS if you like; I think OFS explains its purpose better
```

or merge it into the BEGIN block like

```
    BEGIN { t="chr start"
       for (k=1; k<ARGC; ++k)
          s = s " " 0; t = t OFS ARGV[k] # ditto
       gsub(/.xyz.bed/,"",t); print t
    }
```

For the values you've shown, your external sort (which wasn't needed with the GNU-awk method in the linked Q because gawk can deliver the data lines already sorted) *should* leave the header at the beginning. If other values can occur that wo9uldn't do so, either do the sort *in* the awk script by making (the data part of) the END block

```
       for (k in map)
          print k map[k] | "sort -k1" # see below
```

or use this shell hack to exclude the header from the sort

```
awk ... | { read -r tmp; printf '%s\n' $tmp; sort -k1; }
```

and in either case you appear to want to sort on the combination of 'chr' and 'start' so you should have instead `-k1,2` .

And finally note in any case, including your original *and* the gawk version, you need to pipe through `column -t` to get the visually-aligned columns.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk (for the multi-dimensional arrays, sorting, `BEGINFILE` and `ARGIND`):

```
awk '
  BEGIN {h="chr" OFS "start"; PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"}
  BEGINFILE {f=FILENAME; sub(/\..*/,"",f); h=h OFS f}
  {a[$1 OFS $2][ARGIND]=$3}
  END {
    print h
    for(i in a) {s=i; for(j=1; j<ARGC; j++) s=s OFS a[i][j]+0; print s}
  }' *.bed | column -t
```

`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"` defines the order of `for(i in a)` as *by indices in ascending order compared as strings*. This avoids using `sort` to obtain the expected output order.